Symbolic Computation - Don't Evaluate Integral
I'm following a paper. I've been trying to get Mathematica to help me. Combining equation 1 and equation 2 should result in equation 3.
Equation 1:
\begin{equation}
R=C k^2 T^2 \int_0^{\infty} \ln \left\{1+\mathrm{e}^{-y+\mu_{a}}\right\} \mathrm{d} y
\end{equation}
and Equation 2 (6 in paper):
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d} R^{\frac{1}{2}}} {\mathrm{d} \mu_{b}} = \frac{R^{\frac{1}{2}}} {\mu_{b}} 
\end{equation}
Then, the kicker - direct quote - thus implicit in these two equations is that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\ln \left(1-\mathrm{e}^{\mu_{a}}\right)}{\int_0^{\infty} \ln \left(1+\mathrm{e}^{-y+\mu_{a}}\right) \mathrm{d} y}=\frac{2}{\mu_{\mathrm{b}}}
\end{equation}
I'm struggling to solve this with pen and paper, hence I turned to mathematica. Using Solve, straight out doesn't work. If you reduce the problem - it just solves the integral. Any ideas?
Solve[r == 
   k^2 T^2*Integrate[Log[1 + Exp[-y + mua]], {y, 0, Infinity}] && 
  D[Sqrt[r], mub] == Sqrt[r]/mub, mub]


Note, Equation 1 could be
\begin{equation}
R=C \frac{k^2 T^2}{\left(E_{\mathrm{f}}-k T \mu_{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}} \int_0^{\infty} \ln \left\{1+\mathrm{e}^{-y+\mu_{a}}\right\} \mathrm{d} y,
\end{equation}
It really depends what this quote from the paper means: "if we ignore the term in $E_{\mathrm{f}}$  a procedure which is usually justifiable"

Just replace Integrate with Inactive[Integrate], and it won't compute the integral. Then, if you need to, you Activate the expression to compute the integral/

What are C, k, T and mua? Are they all constants?

$C$,$k$,$T$ are constants, but $\mu_{a}$ changes.

Then mua must be dependent on mub. What is that relation? It is missing in your question.

Equation 3 gives the relationship between the two. It is what I'm trying to determine. I think it is because $R$ is the same $R$ in the two equations. I'm worried the actual paper is wrong. No substitution I make seems to make them align in the way they suggest.

I think it should be $\frac{\mathrm{d} R^{\frac{1}{2}}} {\mathrm{d} \mu_{b}} = \frac{R^{\frac{1}{2}}} {2 \mu_{b}}$. Then it would match the tree equations.

I think I found the solution, by matching the Log[R]/dmu of each expression, e.g. $Activate[
D[Log[Inactivate[
Integrate[Log[1 + Exp[-y + mua]], {y, 0, Infinity}]]], mua]]$ is equated to  $2/\mu_{b}$

I agree with @azerbajdzan
that the relationship between $\mu_a$ and $\mu_b$ is important. In any case, if I ignore or manipulate that relationship, one gets close to the result:
Dt[Sqrt[r[mua]]]/Sqrt[r[mua]] == Dt[mu[mua]]/mu[mua] // 
  Simplify[#, Dt[mua] != 0] &;
% /.
  r -> Function[mua, 
    k^2  T^2*Inactive[Integrate][Log[1 + Exp[-y + mua]], {y, 0, Infinity}]] /.
 {i : Inactive[Integrate][___] /; FreeQ[i, Log] :> Activate[i], 
  mu -> Function[mub, mub/mua]}
(*
Log[1 + E^mua]/
 Inactive[Integrate][
  Log[1 + E^(mua - y)], {y, 0, \[Infinity]}] == 2/mua
*)

It doesn't really make sense that if $\mu_a$ is a constant and $\mu_b$ is variable that the constant expression on the LHS of third equation in the OP would be equal to the variable expression on the RHS.

The derivative is taken with respect to mub not mua, if this is not a mistake in the OP.

@azerbajdzan Yep, as I said, "I ignore or manipulate that relationship." The homogeneous differentials suggest a certain sort of relationship. Here's another guess that yields the result: Dt[Sqrt[r[mua]]]/Sqrt[r[mua]] == Dt[mub]/mub // DivideSides[#, Dt[mua]/2 == Dt[mub]/2, Assumptions -> Dt[mub] != 0] &.  I thought a wrong guess would prompt an explanation. Since the OP has accepted the answer, I can only suppose my posted guess was close enough. If you want clarification, you could try (again) to get the OP to explain. I don't have access to the article, so I can't check myself.

I'd also say that this question is of the kind that in the early days of SE might have been classed as "too localized." I suppose it could be closed for needing details. Or migrated to Math.SE, since I think the mathematics can be done by hand. -- Another note re 2nd guess: $\mu_a$ and $\mu_b$ might be values of a general variable $\mu$ determined by boundary conditions. Can't check though.
